# Problems with tips HTML CSS

Tags: html, css

Help me please, i have tips in my buttons, but when i'm takin mouse from link, the tips are not disappearing.

Please help me in this question. 
Thanks

Css :

```
.photo {
    display: inline-block; /* Строчно-блочный элемент */
    position: relative; /* Относительное позиционирование */
}

.photo:hover::after {
    content: attr(data-title); /* Выводим текст */
    position: absolute; /* Абсолютное позиционирование */
    left: 100%; top: -50%; /* Положение подсказки */
    z-index: 1; /* Отображаем подсказку поверх других элементов */
    background: rgba(255,255,230,0.9); /* Полупрозрачный цвет фона */
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif; /* Гарнитура шрифта */
    font-size: 11px; /* Размер текста подсказки */
    padding: 5px 10px; /* Поля */
    border: 1px solid #333; /* Параметры рамки */
}
```

HTML :

```
<div class="photo" data-title="Remove"><a href="javascript:PopUpShow4({{ item.id }})"><input type="image" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/delete.png" border="0" width="17" height="17" ></a></div>
```

P.S. not disappearing when i taking off the mouse from link and quote in the tips.
The tips must disappeared when i'm take mouse in the tips. Show only when mouse in the button or image

Comment: Working fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/JEa3Q/

Comment: The tips must disappeared when i'm take mouse in the tips. Show only when mouse in the button or image.

Comment: one solution (not really cross-browser) is by using `pointer-events:none` for the `::after`, hovering the `::after` won't trigger hover on `.photo` and then the tooltip will be hidden normally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the tooltip a bit far from the link, so that when you try to mouseover over the tooltip content, it will go out of scope and will disappear.

Like

```
left: 200%; top: -50%; /* Положение подсказки */
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JEa3Q/2/ (Adjust it according to your need)

By the way I'd suggest using jQuery plugin for tooltip, that has these configurable options.

Answer (score 0):

when you hover, the `after` pseudo-element will be visible. To avoid that, declare the `:after` rules normaly on the element, and on `:hover` state, just set it to display: block.